# how to use .serialize() when showing a data into a highchart table

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

guy's i have a problem here.
i have made a highchart table and it working well. but in this case i have a problem with using a `.serialize()` of a textbox from a form. i use serialize because i use a where clause in the php function for the where clause.

this is the code i have use for doing that

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
$tgl1=$_POST['tanggal1'];
$tgl2=$_POST['tanggal2'];

// Data for Titik1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM termocouple where tanggal='$tgl1' and tanggal2='$tgl2' and no='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Titik 1';
while($tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor1'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor2'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor3'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor4'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor5'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor6'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor7'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor8'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor9'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor10'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor11'];
 $rows['data'][] = $tmp['sensor12'];
}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

i cut the php code cz the code to long. but that code i have send above is the part of the whole code.

and this the javascript that i use for show the highchar table

```js
$(function () {
   var chart;
      var data = $("#form_input").serialize(); 
   $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        url: "../php/termocouple/line_termocouple.php",
        success: function(data){
    
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
       renderTo: 'chart1',
       type: 'line'
       
      },
      title: {
       text: 'Termocouple Graph Result'
       
      },
      subtitle: {
       text: ''
      
      },
      xAxis: {
       title: {
        text: 'Sensor'
       },
       categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
      },
      yAxis: {
       title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
       },
       plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
       }]
      },
      tooltip: {
       formatter: function() {
         return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
         this.x +': '+ this.y;
       }
      },
      legend: {
       layout: 'vertical',
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       x: -10,
       y: 120,
       borderWidth: 0
      },
      
      series: json
     });
    });
   
   });
   

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i use that code but the data never showing at highchart table. and the highchar table always been blank..
please somebody help me with that

Comment: where you have defined `json` if defined then add the output of `console.log(json)` in post

Comment: Try to use `data` rather than `json`. If that does not help, provide us with a working example, getting dummy data from some JSON file (e.g. use https://www.json-generator.com).

Comment: i've solve that problem